# If $f_n \to f$ uniformly and $f$ has a discontinuity at $x_0$, then there exists $N$ such that $f_N$ has a discontinuity at $x_0$.

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove or disprove:

If $f_n \to f$ uniformly and $f$ has a discontinuity at $x_0$, then there exists $N$ such that $f_N$ has a discontinuity (of the same type) at $x_0$.

However, I am not sure how to approach this since the discontinuity could be of any type. Is there a way to prove this without using several cases?

Comment: Think about this: suppose $f$ has a simple discontinuity, say removable at $x_0$. Then, for large $n$ you should have $f(x_0)\approx f_n(x_0)$. For $x$ close to $x_0$, if $f_n$ were continuous, $f_n(x)\approx f_n(x_0)$. By the uniform convergence, you should have $f_n(x)\approx f(x)$. But then you should have $f(x)\approx f(x_0)$ which is not the case. Think about where we need uniform convergence (point-wise convergence would not be enough)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**  The contrapositive of this is: If $f_n \to f$ uniformly, and each $f_n$ is continuous at $x_0$ then $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

In this form, you don't need to worry about what type of discontinuity you have to deal with.

**Or better** Assume by contradiction that each $f_n$ is continuous at $0$. Prove that $f$ is continuous at $0$.

**Added** For the same type:

$$f_n= \left\{ 
\begin{array}{lc}
\frac{1}{n} &\mbox{ if } x >0 \\
0 & \mbox{ if }  x<0 \\
1 & \mbox{ if } x=0
\end{array}
\right.$$
converges uniformly to

$$f_n= \left\{ 
\begin{array}{lc}
0 & \mbox{ if }  x \neq 0 \\
1 & \mbox{ if } x=0
\end{array}
\right.$$

Note that $f$ has removable discontinuity while all $f_n$ have jump.

**Added 2:** Try proving instead the following: If $f_n \to f$ uniformly, and 
$$\lim_{x \to x_0^+} f_n(x)=l_n$$
exists for all $n$, then $\lim_{x \to x_0^+} f(x)$ exists.

To do this, show that $l_n$ is Cauchy, deduce that converges to some $l$ and show that $\lim_{x \to x_0^+} f(x)=l$.

Then, do the same for the left limit.

Comment: This isn't the correct contrapositive unless we simply ignore the parethetical.

Comment: @BrianMoehring The problem can be written in the following equivalent form: Let $f_n \to f$ uniformly. If $f$ has a discontinuity at $x_0$ show that there exists some $f_N$ which has a discontinuity at $x_0$... Then the contrapositive is exactly what I wrote.... You are right, as given, the contrapositive is not exactly that one.

Comment: @johnny133253 The stronger claim is not true, see the added example.

Comment: @johnny133253 See the addon to the addon :) Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: $\| f_n -f \|_\infty = \frac{1}{n} \to 0$ so the answer is yes.

Comment: The issue is that you can prove that the left limit and right limits exist at each discontinuity point. But you cannot prove that they are different, which means that the correct statement is " If each $f_n$ has only jump then $f$ can only have jump or removable".... Note that if each $f_n$ has a jump of heigth $\frac{1}{n}$, then $f$ gets a jump of $0$, which becomes removable.

Comment: @johnny133253 Note that for each $x$ you have $|f_n(x)-f(x)|=0$ or $|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\frac{1}{n}$. Therefore, $$|f_n(x)-f(x)| \leq \frac{1}{n} \forall x$$ Uniform convergence follows. The norm is just the supremum of $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ over all $x$.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is continuous at $x_{0}$ if and only if for any sequence $(x_{n})$ such that $x_{n}\rightarrow x_{0}$, it follows that $f(x_{n})\rightarrow f(x_{0})$

Say now $f$ is discontinuous at $x_{0}$, by passing to a subsequence, there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that $|f(x_{n})-f(x_{0})|\geq\epsilon$ for $n\geq N$ for a sequence $(x_{n})$ such that $x_{n}\rightarrow x_{0}$. Then choose an $N$ such that $|f_{N}(x)-f(x)|<(1/3)\epsilon$ for all $x$. We see that
\begin{align*}
|f_{N}(x_{n})-f_{N}(x_{0})|\geq|f(x_{n})-f(x_{0})|-|f_{N}(x_{n})-f(x_{n})|-|f_{N}(x_{0})-f(x_{0})|>(1/3)\epsilon
\end{align*}
for all such $n\geq N$, so $f_{N}(x_{n})$ does not converge to $f_{N}(x_{0})$, $f_{N}$ is discontinuous at $x_{0}$.